# How do I add a class based on the element's value in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to add a class to a table row based on the value of the array it's looping over, as below:

```
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="change in changes|filter:query|orderBy:predicate:reverse">
                <td>{{change.Infrastructure_Change_ID}}</td>
                <td  ng-class="{red: '{{change.Executive_Summary}}' === 'Undefined'}">{{change.Executive_Summary}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

The `Executive_Summary` contains free text, and it will correctly match 'Undefined' and apply class 'red'. However this text can contains quotes, slashes and all sorts of characters that break angular. I'm sure there is a way of adding class 'red' without all the 'Unterminated quote at column..' I have in my log now.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngClass` accepts an expression so you shouldn't need to worry about escaping quotes.

```
<td ng-class="{red: (change.Executive_Summary == undefined)}">
  {{change.Executive_Summary}}
</td>
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/exUFK/)**

Comment: What about if I want to apply the class to the tr element itself?